# what is the error in JS code? The style property of the card element is not assigned because the value type of card is undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.process__card');

card.forEach((cardList) => {
  cardList.addEventListener('mouseover', animationBackround);
  cardList.addEventListener('mouseout', animationBackround);
})

function animationBackround(event) {
  const eventType = event.type;
  const index = Array.from(card).indexOf(event.target);

  if (eventType === 'mouseover') {
    let color1 = getRandomColor();
    let color2 = getRandomColor();
    card[index].style.backgroundColor = `linear-gradient(45deg, ${color1}, ${color2})`
  }

  if (eventType === 'mouseout') {
    card[index].style.backgroundColor = 'none';
  }

}

function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = '0123456ABCDEF';
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }

  return color;
}
```

```css
.process {
  padding-top: 140px;
  &__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 30px;
    width: 1234px;
  }
  &__card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    height: 159px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #191A23;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #191A23;
    &_active {
      height: 279px;
      background-color: #B9FF66;
    }
  }
  &__content {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 41px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1117px;
  }
  &__lable {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    span {
      padding-left: 25px;
      ;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #000;
    }
  }
  &__plus {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #191A23;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 25px;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: #000;
    }
    &:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 5px;
      height: 25px;
      background-color: #000;
    }
    &_active {
      &:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 5px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: #000;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
    }
    &:not(:active) {
      &:before {
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
    }
    &:hover {
      background-color: #B9FF66;
      transition: 0.7s all;
    }
  }
  &__subcontent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 1117px;
    hr {
      width: 1114px;
      background-color: #000;
      height: 1px;
      border: none;
    }
    &_hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    &_active {
      display: block;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
  }
  &__descrp {
    padding: 30px 0 41px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="process__card">
  <div class="process__content">
    <div class="process__lable">01<span>Consultation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="process__plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="process__subcontent process__subcontent_hidden">
    <hr>
    <div class="process__descrp">During the initial consultation, we will discuss your business goals and objectives, target audience, and current marketing efforts. This will allow us to understand your needs and tailor our services to best fit your requirements.</div>
  </div>
```

I believe that the problem lies in the line with the code:

`const index = Array.from(card).indexOf(event.target);`

Perhaps the `Array.from()` array method is not appropriate here..

I did a check and the card elements that come into the array have a negative index (index = -1) when I move the mouse away from the element

Comment: You have a typo: `const letters = '01234567890ABCDEF';` - yours will give random undefined

Answer (score 0):

You already have the target node from `event.target`. So just save that to a local variable in your event handler function and use that directly to update the style.

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.process__card');
const cardArray = Array.from(card)


card.forEach((cardList) => {
  cardList.addEventListener('mouseover', animationBackround);
  cardList.addEventListener('mouseout', animationBackround);
})

function animationBackround(event) {
  const eventType = event.type;
  const target = event.target

  if (eventType === 'mouseover') {
    let color1 = getRandomColor();
    let color2 = getRandomColor();
    target.style.backgroundColor = `linear-gradient(45deg, ${color1}, ${color2})`
  }

  if (eventType === 'mouseout') {
    target.style.backgroundColor = 'none';
  }

}

function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = '0123456ABCDEF';
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }

  return color;
}
```

```html
<div class="process__card">
  <div class="process__content">
    <div class="process__lable">01<span>Consultation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="process__plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="process__subcontent process__subcontent_hidden">
    <hr>
    <div class="process__descrp">During the initial consultation, we will discuss your business goals and objectives, target audience, and current marketing efforts. This will allow us to understand your needs and tailor our services to best fit your requirements.</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `console.log(index)` inside the animationBackground. I would assume it will be `-1` because the event target is one of the inner elements, not the parent `.process__card`.

You can use `event.currentTarget` as outlined in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Answer (score 0):

Delegate and simplify

You also have two typos.

1. the color array is missing digits
2. linear gradient is on background, not backgroundColor

```js
const getRandomColor = () => {
  const letters = '01234567890ABCDEF';
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};

const animationBackround = (event) => {
  const tgt = event.target.closest('.process__card');
  if (!tgt) return;
  const eventType = event.type;
  if (eventType === 'mouseover') {
    let color1 = getRandomColor();
    let color2 = getRandomColor();
    console.log(color1)
    tgt.style.background = `linear-gradient(45deg, ${color1}, ${color2})`
  }
  if (eventType === 'mouseout') {
    tgt.style.background = 'none';
  }
};

const cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');
cardContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', animationBackround);
cardContainer.addEventListener('mouseout', animationBackround);
```

```css
.process {
     padding-top: 140px;
}
 .process__wrapper {
     display: flex;
     margin: 0 auto;
     flex-direction: column;
     gap: 30px;
     width: 1234px;
}
 .process__card {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: #f3f3f3;
     height: 159px;
     border-radius: 45px;
     border: 1px solid #191a23;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #191a23;
}
 .process__card_active {
     height: 279px;
     background-color: #b9ff66;
}
 .process__content {
     display: flex;
     padding-top: 41px;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     width: 1117px;
}
 .process__lable {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     font-size: 60px;
     font-weight: 500;
     color: #000;
}
 .process__lable span {
     padding-left: 25px;
     font-size: 30px;
     font-weight: 500;
     color: #000;
}
 .process__plus {
     display: flex;
     position: relative;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 58px;
     height: 58px;
     background-color: #f3f3f3;
     border-radius: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #191a23;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .process__plus:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 25px;
     height: 5px;
     background-color: #000;
}
 .process__plus:before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 5px;
     height: 25px;
     background-color: #000;
}
 .process__plus_active:before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 5px;
     height: 25px;
     background-color: #000;
     transform: rotate(90deg);
     transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .process__plus:not(:active):before {
     transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .process__plus:hover {
     background-color: #b9ff66;
     transition: 0.7s all;
}
 .process__subcontent {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 1117px;
}
 .process__subcontent hr {
     width: 1114px;
     background-color: #000;
     height: 1px;
     border: none;
}
 .process__subcontent_hidden {
     display: none;
}
 .process__subcontent_active {
     display: block;
     transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .process__descrp {
     padding: 30px 0 41px 0;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: 400;
     color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardContainer">
  <div class="process__card">
    <div class="process__content">
      <div class="process__lable">01<span>Consultation</span>
      </div>
      <div class="process__plus"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="process__subcontent process__subcontent_hidden">
      <hr>
      <div class="process__descrp">During the initial consultation, we will discuss your business goals and objectives, target audience, and current marketing efforts. This will allow us to understand your needs and tailor our services to best fit your requirements.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="process__card">
    <div class="process__content">
      <div class="process__lable">01<span>Consultation</span>
      </div>
      <div class="process__plus"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="process__subcontent process__subcontent_hidden">
      <hr>
      <div class="process__descrp">During the initial consultation, we will discuss your business goals and objectives, target audience, and current marketing efforts. This will allow us to understand your needs and tailor our services to best fit your requirements.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```